# UITableView rows jerking when I am scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

1. In my table view i am using custom cell
2. In each section for one row and each section contains header. The section header increase  or decrease the height  based dynamic text. In that situation, section are jerking when i am scrolling.

   ```
   # pragma mark - UITableView Delegate methods

   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
     return auctionResultAry.count;
   }
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
     return 1;
   }
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   UITableViewCell *cell;
   if (auctionResultAry.count == 0) {
       cell = [self tableView:self.tableView EmptycellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else{
    cell = [self tableView:self.tableView latestofferscellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   self.tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
   }
   return cell;
   }
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView latestofferscellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

   static NSString *cellidentifier=@"Cell";

   subcell=(CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];



   if (subcell==nil)
   {
      subcell =(CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

     }


     subcell.event_auction_name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[auctionResultAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.section ]objectForKey:@"auction_title"]];

   subcell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   return subcell;
    }
   ```

i am writing code in section header

```
  - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
   UIView *headerView;
   headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 60)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


        UILabel *auctionIdLbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(headerView.frame.size.width-115, headerView.frame.origin.y+5, 110, 20)];
        auctionIdLbl.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        auctionIdLbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
        auctionIdLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13];
        auctionIdLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[[auctionResultAry objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"auction_id"]];
        [headerView addSubview:auctionIdLbl];

    UILabel *titleLnbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, headerView.frame.origin.y+5, +headerView.frame.size.width-100, 150)];
    titleLnbl.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    titleLnbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13];
    titleLnbl.numberOfLines=0;
    titleLnbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    titleLnbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[auctionResultAry objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"auction_title"]];
   CGSize size = [self getSizebasedOnText:titleLnbl];
   CGFloat titleLnblHght=size.height;

        CGRect updateLblHght= titleLnbl.frame;
        updateLblHght.size.height=titleLnblHght;
        titleLnbl.frame=updateLblHght;
    [headerView addSubview:titleLnbl];

    return headerView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its due to change in height of row in uitableview.If row height is big jerking is not frequent.